# Evenly spaced button in Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

I'm trying to make 4 buttons, evenly spaced in a portrait view on Android.

The space should scale up and down depending on the screen size, with an even amount of space between each button and the borders.

I tried using linear layout, weight and layout gravity but it seems that I cannot center the button vertically.

Is this a bug of Android layout? More probably is just me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_f"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="btn_f"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_b"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="btn_b"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_a"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="btn_a"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/settings"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Settings"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_f"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn_f"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- etc -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The changes from your original layout are that each inner `LinearLayout` has a height of zero and a gravity (not layout_gravity) of center. This should cause all the inner linear layouts to have the same height, evenly splitting the parent height, without stretching the buttons themselves.

Comment: This way it didn't work... but if you specify both layout_gravity and gravity as center it worked.... for sure android xml interface is POORLY documentated....

Comment: It should be android:layout_gravity="center" not android:gravity="center". It's not necessary to use android:gravity="center" here. gravity tag affects on positioning its content while layout_gravity affects on positioning itself respect to its parent.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 <LinearLayout         
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
  android:layout_height="0dp"         
  android:orientation="horizontal"         
  android:weightSum="1"         
  android:gravity="center">
     <Button             
        android:id="@+id/btn_f"    
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:text="btn_f" />     
 </LinearLayout>
```

This will set the button to occupy only half of the screens length.

Comment: This will stretch the buttons though.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wrapping all buttons in another `LinearLayout` instead of just keeping them in the parent `LinearLayout`.

Remove all those immediate `LinearLayout` so that `android:layout_weight` takes effect.

---

To achieve stretching and spacing

- use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in the buttons themselves
- specify margin for spacing

Comment: this simply stretch the buttons... I want the buttons to be small with space around them... each at the center of a rectangle

Comment: Specifying margin is what I wanted to avoid... you need to put a dimension and even if it is in dip the final effect is not the same on every display... Isn't there an automatic way like with weight?